# admin and end user display is different

Tags: theming

I am new to Drupal, I sub-themed a contributed theme and it works fine. From mytheme.info, I added my css `stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css` and it works fine.

Right now my admin account is logged in Firefox. From Firefox I created a basic page that contains the following:

```
/* Content of my Basic page, Text Format is Full HTML*/
<div class="test">
Hello
</div>

/* From my css file */
.test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

When I saved it and look at the preview, my `<div>` doesn't have the border property, but when I checked it using other browser (Chrome, Safari & IE) the border for div was there.

What happened? Please help!

Comment: could be a browser cache issue, should try to clear the broser cache and then try again

Comment: I tried it but still the same. But when I logout on my browser and check the page, the border on my div was there. The border is hidden when the admin account is logged in.

Comment: do you have different theme for the admin?

Comment: I guess its the same, my small project has only one account and that is admin. My current theme selected is the sub-themed. So I guess its only one.

Comment: I'm going to assume we are talking about drupal 7. go to the path admin/appearance and check the 'administration theme'

Comment: Yes its in Drupal 7, the 'administration theme' was checked already. Also I tried to change the selected Administration Theme to 'Default Selected' And 'My Subtheme' and clear the cache but still not reflecting the css.